# Создание перменных внутри циклв

Tags: python, for

Появился интересный вопрос, буду очень благодарен за ответ, в питоне можно написать цикл for i in range(x) условно, так вот, как создавать в этом цикле списки с именем f_ + i допустим, что бы в будущем использовать их значения.

Answer (score 1):

Так лучше не делать, лучше все значения положить в список

```
arr = []
for i in range(x):
    arr.append(i)
```

Но если очень хочется создать кучу переменных, то попробуйте так:

```
for i in range(x):
    globals()[f"f_{i}"] = i
```

список списков можно сделать так:

```
arr = []
for i in range(x):
    arr.append([])
```

Comment: аххаха проблема в том, что мне нужно создать много списков, в каждый из которых будут класться по 7 значений из большого списка, таким образом я буду сканировать эллементы на нахождения в них нужного мне числа.

Comment: извиняюсь за неправильную формулировку, мне нужно создавать не переменные а списки

Comment: @user422799us А что вам мешает создать список списков или к примеру словарь со списками?

Comment: а это как, не могли бы вы расписать, я просто не давно начал заниматься пайтоном и плохо знаю язык

Comment: @user422799 какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: я ожидаю n-ное кол-во списков, в каждом из которых будет лежать n-ное кол-во значений, но я не знаю, как создавать списки в цикле.

Comment: спасибо, списки в списке очень полезная вещь, но у меня возникает впрос, как обращаться к эллементу в списке списка, допустим мне нужно обратиться к 5 эллементу 7 списка.

Comment: @user422799 `arr[7][5]`

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручил, буду знать.

Comment: Говорю уже на другом этапе реализации проекта, ваш совет с созданием списка списков очень помог, я не раз убеждался в его надобности, спасибо